# How to set texts on MaterialDatePicker?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, material-components-android, material-components, datepickerdialog

To change the title we use this code

```
builder.setTitleText()
```

But how to set selected date range texts: ***"Start date"*** and ***"End date"***.

For example, "Start date" to "Text1" and "End date" to "Text2".

[image]

**Thank you in advance!!!**

Comment: So you want to change "Start date" and "End date" when you select a range ?

Comment: @anehme No, I want to say, for example, I want to change these words and not the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `builder.setSelection` method:

```
    val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    val selection = Pair(startDate,endDate)
    builder.setSelection(selection)
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` are long value

[image]

---

About the **placeholders**.

Currently there isn't a method to change the placeholders for two dates when they are unselected.

However you can override all the existing strings in your project, but this **workaround** can stop to run in the next releases.

Add in your `strings.xml`

```
<string name="mtrl_picker_range_header_unselected"
        description="Placeholders for two dates separated by a dash representing a range [CHAR_LIMIT=60]">Start date – End date</string>
```

[image]

Here the other strings when the dates are selected:

```
  <string name="mtrl_picker_range_header_only_start_selected" description="Placeholders for two dates separated by a dash representing a range where start date has been selected [CHAR_LIMIT=60]">%1$s – End date</string>
  <string name="mtrl_picker_range_header_only_end_selected" description="Placeholders for two dates separated by a dash representing a range where end date has been selected [CHAR_LIMIT=60]">Start date – %1$s</string>
  <string name="mtrl_picker_range_header_selected" description="Two dates separated by a dash representing a range [CHAR_LIMIT=60]">%1$s – %2$s</string>
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele Mariotti. But that's not what I meant. I supplemented my question. I want to change the text itself and not the value.

Comment: @SardorbekMuhammadjonov I've updated the answer also for the placeholders in the header.

Comment: Hi there, I want to also change *Selected date* to *My Custom unselected date*, but updating in String resource file is not working. can you please provide any other way to achieve this .